# Панель управления Ajenti - страчивается установка

Tags: ubuntu

Пытаюсь установить панель управления Ajenti и получаю: Время ожидания соединения истекло При соединении с 217.107.217.56:8000 произошла ошибка. Установка проста- ошибки быть не может. брал инфу [отсюда](https://support.ajenti.org/ru/knowledge-bases/5/articles/1121-installing-on-ubuntu).

Репозитарий сделал, в файл добавил, ключ ввёл, всё Ок.
Install the package:
apt-get update

Получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот почему?

Comment: Я не нашёл никакой информации о поддержке старой версией Ajenti новой версии убунты. Так что подозреваю, что ничего не получится

Comment: А я не увидел в репах 2й версии. Так что походу придётся ставить только через пакетный менеджер питона, как написано на сайте.